# Sub sum query bringing back more results then possible

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently running the following query.( See below) However when I run this query the active users and Suspended users are bring back a far greater result then that's in the database.

I just wondered if you could possibly shed light on the reason why and correct me where I'm going wrong?

```
SELECT c.[Status],
       c.CompanyId,
       c.Name,
       (SELECT count(DISTINCT usr.UserID)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr
               INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
                 ON usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS TotalUsers,
       (SELECT sum (CASE
                      WHEN usr.Status = 2 THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                    END)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr
               INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
                 ON usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS ActiveUsers,
       (SELECT sum (CASE
                      WHEN usr.Status = 3 THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                    END)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[User] usr
               INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
                 ON usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS SuspendedUsers
FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company c
```

Comment: check that your join isn't returning the extra rows by just selecting them out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each of your sub queries you have two tables, one is being joined to the outer query but there is no join between the two inner tables. All of those sub queries are a bit unnecessary, I would rewrite as a simpler query, something like so:

```
 SELECT 
  Company.[Status]
  ,Company.CompanyId
  ,Company.Name
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT usr.UserID) AS TotalUsers
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN usr.Status = 2 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END) AS ActiveUsers
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN usr.Status = 3 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END) AS SuspendedUsers
FROM [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr
  INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
           ON usr.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
GROUP BY
  Company.[Status]
  ,Company.CompanyId
  ,Company.Name
```

If you just wabt a fix for your query as is then try this:

```
SELECT c.[Status],
       c.CompanyId,
       c.Name,
       (SELECT count(DISTINCT usr.UserID)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr
               INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
                 ON usr.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
        WHERE usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS TotalUsers,
       (SELECT sum (CASE
                      WHEN usr.Status = 2 THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                    END)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr
               INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
                 ON usr.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
        WHERE usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS ActiveUsers,
       (SELECT sum (CASE
                      WHEN usr.Status = 3 THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                    END)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[User] usr
               INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
                 ON usr.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
        WHERE usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS SuspendedUsers
FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company c
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would be possible as it is a bigger query than this, and this is just a snippet of it. I tried a similar query before hand some stage during the orginal query it break as well and not bring back the necessary information.

Comment: @Tim - added a straight fix to your query as well.

Comment: @DaveSexton - The sub queries don't need `INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company` at all do they? `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[User] usr WHERE usr.Status = 3 AND usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS SuspendedUsers` looks to be all that is needed though I would use a pivot query rather than correlated sub queries anyway.

Comment: @Martin - agreed but then I wouldn't write a query with 3 similar sub queries in the select in the first place, the performance wouldn't be too great. I did it that way more to show Tim where the problem lay with his version rather than as ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data (it could cause duplicates), but couldnt you use a standard group by and not use sub queries?

```
Select
    c.[Status],
    c.CompanyId,
    c.Name,
    count(distinct usr.UserID) as TotalUsers,
    sum(case when usr.Status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ActiveUsers,
    sum(case when usr.Status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as SuspendedUsers
from [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company  c 
inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr   
    on  usr.CompanyID=c.CompanyID
GROUP BY
    c.[Status],
    c.CompanyId,
    c.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a group by CompanyId and let us know how that worked.